# How much can I rely on the inspectdb command of django for using a large legacy MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, inspectdb

I need to make a website portal for generating reports based on the activities in the library of my college. For that, I have been given a large database with more than 200 tables.

Since I have done website development on django, I was hoping to use that. Now, since I already have a legacy database, I thought of using inspectdb command of django to automatically generate the models according to the database.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > portal/models.py
```

This generated the models for me. I wish to know, how much can I rely on these models. There are multiple OneToOne relations in my database, but django simply made them as ForeignKeys. Could there be more such errors in the models generated? Since the number of tables are large, it's difficult for me to go through every table and check the corresponding models.

If the models so generated can't be trusted, I was hoping to make a website using simple python and connection string for connecting MySQL to python. That allows me to access the database, though I'm not sure how to create a website without using a framework and how to integrate front pages to the website.

Answer (score 3):

It is best to check the [bug tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/) for all known bugs.

The issue you mentioned has already been (recently) fixed in an upcoming release: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30388

> Made inspectdb generate OneToOneFields rather than ForeignKey(unique/primary_key=True).